# Selenium Auto Download Driver on CI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium and serenity to write automation tests for a web application.

I am trying to switch to a new selenium version 4.16.1 together with serenity 4.0.40.
I am aware about the WebDriver is auto downloaded by Selenium from version 4.11 (Might the version is different)

The tests are running fine locally. The tests are failing on the CI tool: Jenkins or TeamCity due the WebDriver I cannot be downloaded.
I think the issue can be the driver cannot be downloaded because the port which is used by selenium to auto download is not opened.

Somebody know which port and host is used by selenium to download the desired WebDriver?